# Why can I successfully pass a Parcelable but not use putExtra, getStringExtra

Tags: android, android-intent

I was trying to pass a String from an AsyncTask to a new Activity in AsyncTask.onPostExecute:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
    Intent displayResponse = new Intent(context, DisplayResponse.class);
    displayResponse.putExtra("package_name.DisplayResponse.response", response);
    displayResponse.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);        
    context.startActivity(displayResponse);
}
```

where `context = (Context) this` in the MainActivity which starts the AsyncTask and passes `context` in the constructor.

In DisplayResponse `getIntent().getStringExtra("package_name.DisplayResponse.response")` is always `null`

If I use a simple Parcelable with just one String and pass that from

```
protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
    Intent displayResponse = new Intent(context, DisplayResponse.class);
    StringParcel sp = new StringParcel(response);
    displayResponse.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("response", sp);
    displayResponse.putExtra("package_name.DisplayResponse.response", bundle);
    context.startActivity(displayResponse);
}
```

I can then use the String in DisplayResponse:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getBundleExtra("package_name.DisplayResponse.response");
StringParcel sp = extras.getParcelable("response");
textView.setText(sp.parcelString);
```

So the question is why does the first method using `putExtra, getStringExtra` fail, whereas the second method using a Parcelable work?

Comment: Perhaps the String in the AsyncTask is created in protected memory space and putExtra only passes a pointer to that memory (not accessible by the activity), whereas a Parcel is created in shared memory?